# Iframe sets wrong width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a page having iframe whose width is assigned dynamically from jquery. Whatever width I set through jquery, the value is incremented automatically and assigned to iframe. I don't understand how and where it changes.

```js
$("#contentViewer").width("1023px");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <iframe id="contentViewer"></iframe>
</div>
```

element rendered in a browser(copied HTML from browser inspect element)

```
<iframe id="contentViewer" style="width: 1026.98px;"></iframe>
```

I expect iframe width to be 1023px, but the iframe rendered with width 1026.98px

On inspecting external CSS includes, I came to know bootstrap CSS makes an issue. if I remove bootstrap CSS than iframe working fine. The bootstrap version I used is 4.3.1

Comment: I edited your code in to an executable snippet where it works fine; the inline width of the iframe exactly matches the value set in jQuery. It's possible you have other code or CSS interfering with the JS, so without seeing that we can't really help you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated my post please see it

Comment: In that case it's most likely the margins/padding which Bootstrap adds causing the discrepancy. Override those in the CSS for the iframe if you don't want them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can identify which bootstrap properties making an issue

Comment: In the inspector you can see all the CSS being applied to an element, and it's source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming due to CSS property inherited from bootstrap.

the property was:

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I changed it to:

```
iframe, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: unset;
}
```

Now iframe set exact value which I assign

Answer (score -1):

Try replace jquery or add css once, this might help you.

```css
iframe{
 border: none;
}
```

```html
$("#contentViewer").css({"width":"1023px"});
```